# How to program XBee S2 (standalone)

Tags: microcontroller, xbee, zigbee

I currently have XBee S2 and I want to program the GPIO pins to switch ON/OFF LED. I saw a lot of tutorial by using external MCU(like Arduino) but in my case I want to use the XBee without any external MCU attached. It seems that XCTU software only allow the GPIO pins to be set HIGH, LOW, input, etc without any logic that can change their conditions.

**So is there any IDE or software that allow XBee GPIO pins to be program?**

Comment: what did Digit tell you when you asked?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: when you called the manufacturer to ask your question about an ide or software to program the XBee GPIO pins, what did they say?

Comment: I spelled Digi wrong, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Digi sells a "Programmable XBee" that includes a separate 8-bit processor you can compile C code to, but that probably isn't what you had in mind.

If you create a network with two XBee modules (A and B), you can have a computer wired to XBee A send a "Remote AT Request" (in API mode) to XBee B to change the I/O pin wirelessly.  If you read through the documentation, you'll find everything you need to know about API mode and the Remote AT Request frame type.

Is that the sort of control you were looking for?  If not, can you describe your use case in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Have you found your solution?

Using XCTU has settings for the DIO pins which include HIGH and LOW. What that means is when the XBee comes out of reset, that will be the default setting. So if set HIGH, coming out of reset, the DIO pin will default HIGH. That is my understanding anyway and that seems to be correct.

I am going through the exercise to have a non-programmable XBee sans micro controller to switch some circuits on and off remotely. The setup is as follows:

1) a control XBee which will be attached to a micro
2) a router XBee without a micro (standalone)

Fairly mundane. What I noticed in my setup was that the standalone XBee's associate pin would toggle for a bit then stop for a bit and repeat. This didn't seem right. When I sent a command from the controller XBee it was hit or miss as to whether the command was carried out by the standalone unit. A bit puzzling.

To check out what was going on with the standalone XBee, I hooked up a computer and fired up XCTU. The problem went away. To cut to the chase, I discovered that when I hooked the computer's serial TX to the XBee's RX pin solved the issue!

My XBees are setup with a level shifting IC so the outside world is 5 volt and the XBee is at 3.3v. My best guess is a floating RX pin which is connected to a level shifter is the culprit. Now holding the RX high at 3.3v seems to overcome the problem.

Then it is just a matter up using the API to set the DIO pin HIGH or LOW

In my case I am toggling DIO_1. Here is the API call from the controller XBee:

7E 00 10 17 01 00 7D 33 A2 00 41 50 EA D5 FF FE 02 44 31 **05** 69

The hex 44 31 is D1 in ASCII the 05 sets the pin HIGH

And for low:

7E 00 10 17 01 00 7D 33 A2 00 41 50 EA D5 FF FE 02 44 31 **04** 6A

Again the 44 31 but now set to 04 - LOW

And the standalone XBee responds properly to the command. No micro attached!

The floating RX pin may or may not be your issue, but the API string should work using your config params. And don't forget the PAN ID must be the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You may want to check the DIO pin drive capability. To drive an LED will require about 20mA.